# Electron.js NSIS installer - "oneClick": false has no effect. Keeps building one click installers

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I want to make a Windows installer with electron.js,
I referred to [nsis config](https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis.html)

I have set **"oneClick": false**

However, whenever I build the app with: **npm run build**

The option always shows as **oneClick=true** on build.

Have also tried **npm run build-installer**, to no avail. Same one click output :-(

I dont understand why is wouldnt accept the oneClick option, it had worked before, now I cant figure out why it just stopped working.

[image]

Here is an excerpt from *package.json*

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make",
    "publish": "electron-forge publish",
    "lint": "echo \"No linting configured\"",
    "build-installer": "electron-builder",
    "build": "electron-builder"
  },
  
  "build": {
    "appId": "apppppppp",
    "win": {
      "target": [
        {
          "target": "nsis",
          "arch": [
            "x64"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "icon": "/src/images/icons/manifest-icon-512.maskable.png"
    }
  },
  "nsis": {
    "oneClick": false,
    "perMachine": false,
    "allowElevation": true,
    "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.63",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.0-beta.63",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.0-beta.63",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.0-beta.63",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.0-beta.63",
    "electron": "16.0.7",
    "build-installer": "electron-builder",
    "build": "electron-builder"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the NSIS tag really relevant here?

Comment: @Anders, Custom NSIS scripts may be required so thats why NSIS also added in the tag

Comment: This question is about electron builder. NSIS does not use JSON anywhere.

Comment: [link](https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis.html#custom-nsis-script)

custom .nsh scripts

Comment: You question is about oneclick, not custom scripts

Answer (score 4):

I put the "nsis" options inside the "build" options and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late, but this might help with your problem if you ever see this.

```
"build": {
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "perMachine": false,
      "allowElevation": true,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
      "deleteAppDataOnUninstall": false,
      "displayLanguageSelector": false,
      "unicode": true,
      "shortcutName": "something",
      "warningsAsErrors": true,
      "runAfterFinish": true,
      "createDesktopShortcut": "always",
      "createStartMenuShortcut": true,
      "menuCategory": false
    },
    "win": {
      "target": [
        {
          "target": "nsis",
          "arch": [
            "x64",
            "ia32"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "icon": "something.png"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).